# NFS Stale File Handle which survives client reboot

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

After an unscheduled reboot of our NFS server last night, a few of the clients reported "Stale NFS file handle".

All but one of these were fine after a reboot though one client is still giving errors after several reboots and manual umount/mounting of the filesystem.

What might be causing this be, and what could be done about it?

The OS is Ubuntu 10.04, with NFSv3.

Comment: Is the error you are still seeing after reboots and remounts "stale file handle", or is it another error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS locks can survive a reboot.  They should eventually timeout, but sometime you need to shutdown NFS and clear the lock directory manually.

I believe I usually run into this issue when the export is not available when the system comes back up.  If I remember right the locks are maintained in `/var/lib/nfs/sm`.

Comment: They did eventually clear.  I can't tell if your suggestions of `/var/lib/nfs/sm` is right, but thanks.

Comment: @jpnp: I believe the timeouts are quite long.  I was never able to wait for them to timeout.